# Angular White Space At Top Of Page

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I recently created an Angular project with a red navigation bar at the top of the page.

At the start the nav bar was directly at the top of the page but later on I realised that there was a small white space created above it.

I then discovered that I could highlight a part of the space and thought that it was not a CSS issue but rather a space placed by mistake.

Photo of white space:

[White Space Above Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxV8D.png)

Photo of console when I inspect the highlighted area:

[Console: Inspect White Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iki6N.png)

I think that the issue might be caused by the "&nbsp ;" but I don't know how to find it in my HTML files.

Here is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MediStockWeb</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-base/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-buttons/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-inputs/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-popups/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-lists/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-calendars/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.scss:

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #eb4848;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
}

.nav-link {
  color: black;
  font-size: large;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: x-large;
}

.navLogo {
  padding: 5px;
}


table {

  border: 2px solid #000;

  th {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: #ec3c3c;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: 550;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  td {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

select {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.btn {
  border: 0.25px solid #000;
}

label{
  font-size: large;
}

.errorMessage {
  color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input.ng-invalid.ng-touched,
select.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.mat-icon {
  margin: 5px;

  &:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: rgb(94, 92, 92)
  }

}

.nav-item  {

  &:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
  }

}

.modal-title {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.modal-body {
font-size: 18px;
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide the HTML and CSS code of that part please?

Comment: Specifically this should be in `index.html`.

Comment: @Castle I added it to the question :)

Comment: @GunnarB. I posted the index.html. Personally I could not find anything there that could be causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's something in the component being displayed in your route or one of the scripts you include.  It's not really good practice to place `<link>` elements in your body even if they are [one of the body-ok types](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#body-ok).

If I had to guess, I would say that you are including a script for ej2 somewhere in your build.  It probably thinks it has to add the stylesheet `<link>` elements and does it inappropriately.

Comment: I will take a look at it, thank you!